# How to Share Variable Across the in-class def in Python

Tags: python, pandas, class

```
class Dataframe: #Recommended to instatiate your dataframe with your csv name.
    """
    otg_merge = Dataframe("/Users/zachary/Desktop/otg_merge.csv") #instaiate as a pandas dataframe
    """
    def __init__(self, filepath, filename = None):
        pd = __import__('pandas') #import pandas when the class is instatiated 
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.filename = filename

    def df(self): #it makes the DataFrame
        df = pd.read_csv(self.filepath, encoding = "cp949", index_col= 0)  #index col is not included
        return df

    def shape(self): #it returns the Dimension of DataFrame
        shape = list(df.shape)
        return shape

    def head(self): #it reutrns the Head of Dataframe
        primer = pd.DataFrame.head(df)
        del primer["Unnamed: 0"]
        return primer

    def cust_types(self): #it returns the list of cust_type included in .csv
        cust_type = []
        for i in range(0, shape[0]):
            if df.at[i, "cust_type"] not in cust_type: #if it's new..
                cust_type.append(df.at[i, "cust_type"]) #append it as a new list element
        return cust_type
```

I am doing some wrapping pandas functions wrapping for whom doesn't necessarily need to know the pandas.

If you see the code, at the third def, shape returns shape as a list of such as [11000, 134] as a xdim and ydim.

Now I'd like to use the shape again at the last def cust_types, however,, it returns the shape is not defined.

How can I share the variable "share" across defs in the same class?

- intersetingly, I didn't do nth, but the df is shared from second df to thrid shape without error

Comment: Just make your `df` an instance variable. In your `df` method set your `df` to `self.df` and then you can access it from any other method of the same class as `self.df`.

Comment: @thx. one more question- why at the above code, only df shared across the dfs?

Comment: I think, you should first get familiar with oop in python. It's not that hard in python, [this kind of resources](https://medium.com/the-renaissance-developer/python-101-object-oriented-programming-part-1-7d5d06833f26) my help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First prepend "self." in all your attributes which you will know after trying out some python oops  tutorials. Another issue which you might miss is

> def df(self):
>         df = pd.read_csv(self.filepath, encoding = "cp949", index_col= 0)
>         return df

Here, the method name and the variable name takes the same name which is fine, if the variable name is not an instance attribute as it is not. But in case if you prepend "self." and make it as an instance attribute, your instance attribute will be self.df and it can't be a function after the first function call self.df().